# Measure performance of a fast bash script?

Tags: bash, performance

In programming languages I would typically measure the performance of something relatively fast (<1 second completion) by looping it a few thousand times, and then getting the average time per completion.

How would I do the same in bash to compare the execution performance of two very fast commands?

Comment: use:  $ time 'command'  and $ man time for details on the time command itself.

Comment: @WillemK I thought that only executes it once though to measure the speed? Or does it average a few executions?

Answer (score 5):

It's better to use something like `time` command.

Bash also has a `time` built-in, what I'm suggesting is using `time` binary located at: `/usr/bin/time`.

For one runtime:

```
command time -f "\nElapsed: %E \nUser: %U \nSystem: %S \nMemory: %M\n" \
./MyCommand 1> /dev/null
```

Which outputs:

```
Elapsed: 0:00.01 
User: 0.00 
System: 0.00 
Memory: 2412
```

- `command`: forces bash to use `/usr/bin/time` instead of `time` built-in.

You can use `time` with a loop to get a "avrage", "min", "max" of a specific resource say memory:

This code will run `./COMMAND` commands 1000 times, then prints out the "min, max, avg" of its total (data+stack+text) memory usage.

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfile=`mktemp`
for i in {1..1000}; do  command time -ao $tmpfile -f "%K" ./COMMAND 1>/dev/null; done;
awk 'NR == 1 {min = $0} $0 > max {max = $0} {total += $0} END {print total/NR, min, max}' $tmpfile
rm $tmpfile
```

Here is the output:

```
2436.89 2524 2324
```

You can change `%K` with:

- `%E`: Elapsed real time
- `%I`: Number of file inputs
- `%P`: Percentage of the CPU that this job got
- `%k`: Number of signals delivered to the process
- `%U`: CPU usage in user mode
- `%S`: CPU usage in kernel mode

See `man time`

Thanks to muru for writing a more clear `awk` statement.

Comment: That's an odd way to do it... Instead of the `echo $(...) | tr ' ' '\n'`, you could just do `for i in {1..1000}; do  command time -f "%K\n" ./COMMAND 2>&1 1>/dev/null; done`. And in `awk`, uninitialized variables get evaluated to 0, so `awk '$0 < min {min = $0} $0 > max {max = $0} {total += $0} END {print total/NR; max, min}'` The GNU `time` command also supports logging to a file, `-o file`, so you can use that, and then run `awk` on that file later, instead of redirecting stderr and stdout

Comment: oh, yes, min needs to be initialised to something other than 0. `-v min=foo`, or `NR == 1 {min = $0}`. Sorry about that

Comment: @muru fixed it ;) thanks again :-) gotta learn `awk` I guess :D

Comment: A problem with this method is that /bin/time only uses centisecond resolution for CPU, so for very fast commands CPU will be zero.  For example, the CPU used by running `sleep .1`, is rounded down to 0.00, so no matter how many iterations it runs, the CPU total will always be zero. (the built-in bash time has millisecond resolution). Also, the Elapsed time printed by `%E` is in the form `[hours:]minutes:seconds.xxx` (i.e. 0:00.11), so you can't total it with the simple awk `+` operator.

Comment: built-in `time`  have not `-f` option, that's why you need to use `command` for `/usr/bin/time`. too bad git bash have not `/usr/bin/time` in windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Python's `timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) (which is usually used for python code snippets), with the [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) function to run external commands:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'import subprocess' 'subprocess.call(["sleep", "0.1"])' 
10 loops, best of 3: 103 msec per loop
```

You can change the number of loops with `-n`:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -n 5 -s 'import subprocess' 'subprocess.call(["sleep", "0.1"])' 
5 loops, best of 3: 103 msec per loop
```

And since `sleep 0.1` should sleep for 100 ms, it looks like the measurement is pretty accurate.

Also see:

- [How to use the timeit module on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24105845/2072269)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got it:

```
N=10000
time(for i in $(eval echo "{1..$N}"); do
./mycommand &>/dev/null
done)
```

Comment: `for i in $(seq 1 $N)` instead of the `eval echo` would be simpler. Or `for ((i = 0; i < N; i++))`

Comment: Don't use eval, it's both redundant here and recommended to be avoided in general. Use what muru suggested

Comment: Please be aware, that sometimes the system will understand, that you want it to do the same thing many times, and find some shortcut, so that the second, third ... iterations will be faster than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

In general the [easy way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-to-get-execution-time-of-a-script-effectively) is to do `time ./myscript.sh` but this will show you zero second as your script is really fast.

Instead use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014823/how-to-profile-a-bash-shell-script-slow-startup) that use GNU `date` (able to show nanoseconds) and `PS4`.

Comment: Please don't give links as answers. Instead, quote the relevant information from the link and give the link as a reference. Here, for example, you're linking to a question with multiple answers. Which one is the OP supposed to use? How would they adapt it for their specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something, and came across both this question and:

https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine - "A command-line benchmarking tool"

YMMV